# GSON String under key?

Tags: java, gson

I am successfully writing `.json` to a file from an object using the following code:

```
public static void savePlayerGson(PlayerCharacter playerCharacter) {
    try {
        Writer writer = new FileWriter(KRYMMO.getInstance().getDataFolder() + "/data/playercharacter.json");
        new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(playerCharacter, writer);
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        KRYMMO.getInstance().getLogger().severe(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The output of this code (in the file) is this:

```
{
  "owner": "5608aa78-d160-4757-8192-426dfea2bf7e",
  "playerCollections": {
    "owner": "5608aa78-d160-4757-8192-426dfea2bf7e",
    "unlockedCollections": {}
  },
  "experience": 0.0,
  "experienceNextLevel": 200.0,
  "level": 1,
  "maxLevel": 100,
  "Health": 100.0,
  "MaxHealth": 100.0,
  "Mana": 100.0,
  "MaxMana": 100.0,
  "Defense": 0.0,
  "Strength": 0.0,
  "Intelligence": 0.0,
  "PetLuck": 0.0,
  "Speed": 100.0,
  "CritChance": 2.0,
  "CritDamage": 50.0,
  "SeaCreatureChance": 20.0,
  "MagicFind": 0.0,
  "HealthIcon": "§c?",
  "ManaIcon": "§b?",
  "DefenseIcon": "§a?",
  "StrengthIcon": "§c?",
  "IntelligenceIcon": "§b?",
  "PetLuckIcon": "§d?",
  "SpeedIcon": "§f?",
  "CritChanceIcon": "§9?",
  "CritDamageIcon": "§9?",
  "SeaCreatureChanceIcon": "§3?",
  "MagicFindIcon": "§b?",
  "HealthName": "§cHealth",
  "ManaName": "§bMana",
  "DefenseName": "§aDefense",
  "StrengthName": "§cStrength",
  "IntelligenceName": "§bIntelligence",
  "PetLuckName": "§dPet Luck",
  "SpeedName": "§fSpeed",
  "CritChanceName": "§9Crit Chance",
  "CritDamageName": "§9Crit Damage",
  "SeaCreatureChanceName": "§3Sea Creature Chance",
  "MagicFindName": "§bMagic Find"
}
```

However, what I want the output to be is:

```
{
   "thePlayerIdHere":{
      "owner":"5608aa78-d160-4757-8192-426dfea2bf7e",
      "playerCollections":{
         "owner":"5608aa78-d160-4757-8192-426dfea2bf7e",
         "unlockedCollections":{
            
         }
      },
      "experience":0.0,
      "experienceNextLevel":200.0,
      "level":1,
      "maxLevel":100,
      "Health":100.0,
      "MaxHealth":100.0,
      "Mana":100.0,
      "MaxMana":100.0,
      "Defense":0.0,
      "Strength":0.0,
      "Intelligence":0.0,
      "PetLuck":0.0,
      "Speed":100.0,
      "CritChance":2.0,
      "CritDamage":50.0,
      "SeaCreatureChance":20.0,
      "MagicFind":0.0,
      "HealthIcon":"§c?",
      "ManaIcon":"§b?",
      "DefenseIcon":"§a?",
      "StrengthIcon":"§c?",
      "IntelligenceIcon":"§b?",
      "PetLuckIcon":"§d?",
      "SpeedIcon":"§f?",
      "CritChanceIcon":"§9?",
      "CritDamageIcon":"§9?",
      "SeaCreatureChanceIcon":"§3?",
      "MagicFindIcon":"§b?",
      "HealthName":"§cHealth",
      "ManaName":"§bMana",
      "DefenseName":"§aDefense",
      "StrengthName":"§cStrength",
      "IntelligenceName":"§bIntelligence",
      "PetLuckName":"§dPet Luck",
      "SpeedName":"§fSpeed",
      "CritChanceName":"§9Crit Chance",
      "CritDamageName":"§9Crit Damage",
      "SeaCreatureChanceName":"§3Sea Creature Chance",
      "MagicFindName":"§bMagic Find"
   }
}
```

How can I add the key to my `.json` like that? Also as a note, I can get the playerID. I simply placed "playerIDHere" to illustrate where I want the key I specify.

Also, if it changes anything, how can I then deserialize the `.json` under the key back into my object?

Comment: Use `Map<String, YourType>` and parameterized type (`ParameterizedType`) or type tokens (`TypeToken`; essentially a parameterized type holder) to specify the map key and value types. BTW, your `writer` may be not closed hence causing resource leakage.